# plumbum : SSH to my remote server

Tags: ssh, plumbum

Good day, I am using plumbum on anaconda to connect to my remote server A.

I have create a new user linux2 and assigned a publickey to that user. then changed the permission on the .ssh and authorizedkeys as

> chmod 700 /home/linux2/.ssh chmod 600
>
> /home/linux2/.ssh/authorized_keys

When i try the code :

```
from plumbum import SshMachine
rem=SshMachine("000.000.131.110",user="linux2",Password = "password")
```

I am getting the below error: Please assist

> CommandNotFound                           Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 # YOUR CODE HERE
>         2 from plumbum import SshMachine
>   ----> 3 rem=SshMachine("000.000.131.110",user="linux2",password = "password")
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plumbum\machines\ssh_machine.py
>   in **init**(self, host, user, port, keyfile, ssh_command, scp_command,
>   ssh_opts, scp_opts, password, encoding, connect_timeout, new_session)
>        77         if ssh_command is None:
>        78             if password is not None:
>   ---> 79                 ssh_command = local["sshpass"]["-p", password, "ssh"]
>        80             else:
>        81                 ssh_command = local["ssh"]
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plumbum\machines\local.py
>   in **getitem**(self, cmd)
>       206             else:
>       207                 # search for command
>   --> 208                 return LocalCommand(self.which(cmd))
>       209         else:
>       210             raise TypeError("cmd must not be a RemotePath: %r" % (cmd,))
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plumbum\machines\local.py
>   in which(cls, progname)
>       176             if path:
>       177                 return path
>   --> 178         raise CommandNotFound(progname, list(cls.env.path))
>       179 
>       180     def path(self, *parts):
>
> CommandNotFound: ('sshpass', [, , , , , , , , , ,
>   , ,
>   , , , , ,
>   ,
>   ,
>   ,
>   ,
>   ,
>   ])

Answer (score 2):

Based on your output, you appear to be running this from a Windows machine.  According to the [plumbum docs](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote.html#remote-machines), you should use PuttyMachine (requires [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to be installed), or ParamikoMachine for remote ssh connections on Windows.